# Facebook login using FB PHP sdk not working

Tags: php, facebook

I am working on login using FB id feature for my application and started with downloading the SDK for FB connect from GITHUB (facebook-php-sdk-master).

Within the application it has two examples 1) For Javascript api and 2) For PHP api.
I want to use the PHP SDK to neglect the javascript disable feature in users website.
Now I entered my applications

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'deliberately blank',
      'secret' => '',
    ));
```

I logged in to facebook to check if its working and it always returns **0** even if the user logs in.
I just tried to print the user variable

```
   $user = $facebook->getUser();
   print_r($user);
```

I checked the app settings and I have them correctly set for domain,URL and Canvas URL.I have also disabled the sandbox mode for it.

Is this an issue with the plugin as the session is not captured or I am doing something wrong here?
 Anyone worked on or faced similar issue please share your insights as I am stuck and I tried to print the session data using `$_SESSION` which returns an array which has

```
Array ( [fb_117096311791424_state] => 5faba08750cd6456hbf27580df3b371 )
```

But I don't get the user info.Is there any other way to achieve it?Any alternative API etc?

**UPDATE for code**:

```
define('HTTP_SERVER', "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]); // eg, http://localhost - should not be empty for productive servers
define('HTTPS_SERVER', ''); // eg, https://localhost - should not be empty for productive servers
define('BASE_URL', HTTP_SERVER.'/'); // eg, https://localhost - should not be empty for productive servers

if(HTTP_SERVER == 'http://localhost'){
    define('DOCUMENT_SERVER', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/XYZ/');
}else{
    define('DOCUMENT_SERVER', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'); 
}
require(DOCUMENT_SERVER.'includes/applicationTop.php');
$dataObj = new Database();
$generalObj = new General();

file_get_contents('http://www.ABC.com/login/facebookConnect/fbmain.php');
//require_once('http://www.ABC.com/login/facebookConnect/fbmain.php');

/**
* check if user login first time or second time with facebook, records stored in table and session.
**/

if (!empty($user))
{
$firstName = $userInfo['first_name'];
$lastName = $userInfo['last_name'];
$userName = $userInfo['username'];
$gender = $userInfo['gender'];
$email = $userInfo['email'];
$birthday = $userInfo['birthday'];

$userImage = $fqlResult[0]['pic_square'];
$addressName = $fqlResult[0]['hometown_location']['name'];
$addressCity = $fqlResult[0]['hometown_location']['city'];
$addressState = $fqlResult[0]['hometown_location']['state'];
$addressCountry = $fqlResult[0]['hometown_location']['country'];
$addressZip = $fqlResult[0]['hometown_location']['zip'];

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$date = date('Y-m-d');

$accountId = strtolower($generalObj->fnCreatePassword(8));


/**
* check user first time login or not with facebook login.
**/

$queryUser = "SELECT tbl_login.userId,tbl_login.accountId,tbl_login.emailId FROM tbl_login WHERE tbl_login.emailId='$email'";
$resultUser = $dataObj->tep_db_query($queryUser);
$userInfo = $dataObj->getRecord($resultUser);
$checkUser = $dataObj->getNumRows($queryUser);

if($checkUser == '0' || $checkUser == '')
{
    /**
    * if user first time login with facebook then records are inserted into table.
    **/
    $qyery = "INSERT INTO ".TABLE_LOGIN." (accountId, emailId,activeFlag,facebook_Userid) VALUES('$accountId','$email','1','$username')";
    $data = $dataObj->tep_db_query($qyery);
    $userID = $dataObj->tep_db_insert_id();
    if(!empty($userID))
    {   
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".TABLE_USER_INFO." (userId,fName,lName,address,city,country,state,postalCode,emailId,user_dob,profile_Image,user_ip,user_date,activeFlag) VALUES('$userID','$firstName','$lastName','$addressName','$addressCity','$addressCountry','$addressState','$addressZip','$email','$birthday','$userImage','$ip','$date','1')";
        $data = $dataObj->tep_db_query($sql);
    }
    //$_SESSION["gobiggiuserFaceBook"] = true;
    $_SESSION["UserId"] = $userID;
    $_SESSION["username"] = $accountId;
    $_SESSION["emailId"] = $email;
    $_SESSION["ProfileImage"] = $userImage;

}
else
{
    /**
    * updated user's info incase user has been updated own profile's records on facebook.
    **/
    //QUery for update

    /**
    * If user have already login with facebook then records are taking into session
    **/

    $_SESSION["UserId"] = $userInfo['userId'];
    $_SESSION["username"] = $userInfo['accountId'];
    $_SESSION["emailId"] = $userInfo['emailId'];
    $_SESSION["ProfileImage"] = $userImage['profile_Image'];    

}

$sessionUserid = (!empty($_SESSION["UserId"])) ? $_SESSION["UserId"] : '' ; 

if(!empty($sessionUserid)){
    echo "herererere in dashboard part";
    //exit;
    header("Location:".USER_DASHBOARD."userDashboard.php");
    exit();
    //$generalObj->tep_redirect(FILE_PATH.'userDashboard.php');
}else{
    echo "herererere in login part";
    exit;
    header("Location:".LOGIN."login.php");
    exit();
    //$generalObj->tep_redirect(FILE_PATH.'login.php');
}
}
else
{
    //echo LOGIN.USER_DASHBOARD;
    //exit();
    /*I always end up here*/
    header("Location:".LOGIN."login.php");
    exit();
    //$generalObj->tep_redirect(FILE_PATH.'login.php');
}
```

This is the `fbmain.php`

```
$fbconfig['appid' ]     = "deliberately blank";
$fbconfig['secret']     = " ";
$fbconfig['baseurl']    = "http://www.ABC.com/login/facebookConnect/facebookHome.php"; 


if (isset($_GET['request_ids'])){
    //user comes from invitation
    //track them if you need
}

$user            =   null; //facebook user uid
try{

    require_once "facebook.php";
}
catch(Exception $o){
    error_log($o);
}
// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
));

//Facebook Authentication part
$user       = $facebook->getUser();
// We may or may not have this data based 
// on whether the user is logged in.
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know 
// the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don’t know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.
//print_r($user);
//exit;
$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope'         => 'email,offline_access,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history,user_about_me,user_hometown',
            'redirect_uri'  => $fbconfig['baseurl']
        )
);

$logoutUrl  = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    //you should use error_log($e); instead of printing the info on browser
    d($e);  // d is a debug function defined at the end of this file
    $user = null;
  }
}


//if user is logged in and session is valid.
if ($user){
    //get user basic description
    $userInfo           = $facebook->api("/$user");
   // print_r($userInfo);
    //Retriving movies those are user like using graph api
    try{
        $movies = $facebook->api("/$user/movies");
    }
    catch(Exception $o){
        d($o);
    }

    //update user's status using graph api
    //http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/
    if (isset($_GET['publish'])){
        try {
            $publishStream = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array(
                'message' => "", 
                'link'    => '',
                'picture' => '',
                'name'    => '',
                'description'=> ''
                )
            );
            //as $_GET['publish'] is set so remove it by redirecting user to the base url 
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            d($e);
        }
        //echo "login successs!!!";exit;
        $redirectUrl     = $fbconfig['baseurl'] . '/login.php?success=1';
        header("Location: $redirectUrl");
    }

    //update user's status using graph api
    //http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/
    if (isset($_POST['tt'])){
        try {
            $statusUpdate = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array('message'=> $_POST['tt']));
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            d($e);
        }
    }

    //fql query example using legacy method call and passing parameter
    try{
        $fql    =   "select name, hometown_location, sex, pic_square from user where uid=" . $user;
        $param  =   array(
            'method'    => 'fql.query',
            'query'     => $fql,
            'callback'  => ''
        );
        $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
    }
    catch(Exception $o){
        d($o);
    }
}

function d($d){
    //echo '<pre>';
    //print_r($d);
    //echo '</pre>';
}
```

The other files are from the SDK itself.

Regards

Comment: so basically you are able to login into facebook and come back to your site, but not able to get any of the details from fb?!?!?!

Comment: No,actually if I enter my login details,I am not redirected to my dashboard(page after login) instead I come back to the login page and with no trace of my login.If I am already logged in,on another tab,it just refreshes and brings me back to the same page. **In a way you are correct!**

Comment: Could you pls post your complete code...

Comment: @elavarasanlee updated with my code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**. Change `file_get_contents('file_path');` to `require_once('file_path');` 
**2**. In else condition, where you are checking **1st time user**, you have used

```
$_SESSION["UserId"] = $userInfo['userId'];
$_SESSION["username"] = $userInfo['accountId'];
$_SESSION["emailId"] = $userInfo['emailId'];
$_SESSION["ProfileImage"] = $userImage['profile_Image'];
```

All these values are wrong, I mean the index used for `$userInfo` are wrong! Instead use as follows:

```
$_SESSION["UserId"] = $userInfo['id']; //or $user
$_SESSION["username"] = $userInfo['username']; 
$_SESSION["emailId"] = $userInfo['email'];
$_SESSION["ProfileImage"] = $userImage; //not $userImage['profile_Image']
```

Just these two changes, and you are through.

Comment: Its actually like this `$sessionUserid = (!empty($_SESSION["UserId"])) ? $_SESSION["UserId"] : '';` Updated the question. I have set it to the session ` $_SESSION["UserId"] = $userID;`

Comment: Okay lets debug and start this from basic. after downloading the files did U try using the code in **example.php** file???

Comment: Why have you used `file_get_contents('file_path');` instead of `include_once 'file_path';`

Comment: @coderunner Its solved... Try the changes that I've mentioned. I've updated my answer.